# WSO2 IOT server

Tags: wso2, raspberry-pi3

I am using WSO2 IOT server with raspberrypi 3. I am in the beginning level. I was able to switch on/off the LED bulb which is connected to raspberrypi with this command.

curl -k -X POST "https://172.16.13.86:8243/raspberrypi/1.0.0/device/us310v497by0/bulb?state=on" -H "accept: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer 739e2223-62b6-3a24-890f-5b6e610ed6d2"

Now I want to get the current temperature which is detected by the dht11 sensor. I want to know a same type of command  which I used for switch on/off the LED bulb. Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try:

curl -X GET --header 'Accept: application/json' 'https://ServerIP:9443/api/device-mgt/v1.0/events/last-known/deviceType/deviceId' -H "Authorization: Bearer token"

Comment: thanks a lot... But it gives an error like this..    I tried 3 types of access tokens. This is the error.                                                                                                                       {"fault":{"code":900908,"message":"Resource forbidden ","description":"Access failure for API: /api/device-mgt/v1.0/events/1.0.0, version: 1.0.0 status: (900908) - Resource forbidden "}}

Comment: curl -v -k -X GET --header 'Accept: application/json' 'https://172.16.13.86:8243/api/device-mgt/v1.0/events/last-known/raspberrypi/us310v497by0' -H "Authorization: Bearer cfe03639-4eca-3766-ac11-df23a769279e"

Comment: Well, it seems there is issue of permission. Have you followed this for generating access token? https://docs.wso2.com/display/IoTS310/Generating+the+Access+Token#036bc691f74f47a69104b8b270a7b989

Comment: Yes.. I did it.. but it gives an error like this. Unable to search the table - IOT_PER_DEVICE_STREAM_CARBON_SUPER_RASPBERRYPI for tenant id : -1234 with query : meta_deviceId:qec50zwoao9u. &lt;!--  ~ Copyright (c) 2016, WSO2 Inc. (http://www.wso2.org) All Rights Reserved.  ~  ~ WSO2 Inc. licenses this file to you under the Apache License,  ~ Version 2.0 (the &quot;License&quot;); you may not use this file except  ~ in compliance with the License.  ~ You may obtain a copy of the License at  ~  ~ http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.

Comment: And also I can't see device analytics... Analytics graph does not show anything about past. But I can see my realtime data in the graph at any time.

Comment: Please login to analytics server admin console and explore IOT_PER_DEVICE_STREAM_CARBON_SUPER_RASPBERRYPI table and checkout if your data is there. After that you can try another approach by trying to access data through analytics API. DAS URL: https://<IOTS_HOST>:9445/portal. Ref:  https://docs.wso2.com/display/DAS310/Analytics+REST+API+Guide

Comment: I checked it.. When I was logging to it it did not have any dashbords. I created a dashboard. But there are no any tables.

Comment: I ran this code.                                                        curl -v -k -X GET "https://172.16.13.86:9445/analytics/table_exists?table=IOT_PER_DEVICE_STREAM_CARBON_SUPER_RASPBERRYPI" -H 'content-type: application/json' -H 'Accept: application/json' -H "Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4="                                                             This is the output: {"status":"non-existent","message":"Table : IOT_PER_DEVICE_STREAM_CARBON_SUPER_RASPBERRYPI does not exist."}

Comment: What can I do to creat this table?

Comment: Please try this API and share response: https://docs.wso2.com/display/DAS310/Retrieving+the+List+of+Tables+of+All+Record+Stores+via+REST+API

Comment: It worked... Thanks a lot... Now I can see all the records of the table. I will find a way to get last known. This was the problem when I run curl -v -k -X GET --header 'Accept: application/json' 'https://172.16.13.86:8243/api/device-mgt/v1.0/events/last-known/raspberrypi/us310v497by0' -H "Authorization: Bearer 7f43371c-3c89-341f-a0d5-3088b71018d1"  this one, it search for a table called IOT_PER_DEVICE_STREAM_CARBON_SUPER_RASPBERRYPI. But the actual table name is iot_per_device_stream_raspberrypi_temperature.

Comment: Welcome, can you accept the answer so that it will be helpful for others as well?

Comment: Okay.. did it.. And now my device is working correctly.. thanks

Comment: Can I know a similar type command to get the current state of the bulb... Not to switch on & off. Just display that the bulb is working or not.

Comment: For that, you will need to modify device agent and device plugin. Otherwise you can create custom device type with desired parameters/properties and develop custom device firmware/client.

Comment: How can I add the scope to my access token generation CURL command?    scope is pearm:raspberrypi:enroll

Comment: curl -v -k -d "grant_type=password&username=admin&password=admin&scope=pearm:raspberrypi:enroll" -H "Authorization: Basic <BASE 64 ENCODED CLIENT_ID:CLIENT_SECRET>" -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" https://<IOTS_HOST>:8243/token

Comment: Add all scopes in scope field i.e. scope=perm:sign-csr perm:admin:devices:view perm:admin:topics:view perm:roles:add perm:roles:add-users

Comment: Can You please help on this?????     https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54359237/wso2-iot-server-modification

Comment: Can u please help on this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54743538/wso2-iot-server-with-raspberry-pi