# WSO2 IOT SERVER MODIFICATION

Tags: wso2

I want to modify my wso2 iot server to do the following task. Now I have only one LED bulb which is connected to my RASPBERRY PI. I want to increase the number of LEDs up to 3. Now the system turn on the only LED when the temperature in greater than 28 C. I want to turn on the 2nd LED when the temperature in greater than 30 C & turn on the 3rd LED when the temp is greater then 35 C. So when the temperature is 36 C all 3 LEDs are working. 
How can I do this? Can I modify some files in WSO2 iot server & raspberry pi agent? If it is possible then what are those files and what should be modified? 
Or can I write a new file or files to do that one? If it is possible then how can I do that?

Your help on this is very much appreciated.

Comment: You will need to modify default raspberry pi device type with desired attributes: https://docs.wso2.com/display/IoTS310/Creating+a+New+Device+Type+via+the+Device+Management+Console

Comment: Following link will also be helpful. You can also create your custom device type with all required attributes and parameters, and also can write custom device firmware. https://docs.wso2.com/display/IoTS310/Creating+a+Fire+Alarm+Device+Type+via+the+Console

Comment: Following link will help you out in exploring how you can publish custom data from device corresponding to particular device type, and also how to retrieve operations from server. https://docs.wso2.com/display/IoTS310/Creating+a+New+Device+Type+via+APIs

Comment: Those are helped... Thenk you....

Comment: Now I have connected two raspberry pis to my server from admin user. Those two have different device ids. But when I run both testAgents when first one is connected other one is disconnected. when the second one is connected first one is disconnected. I tried with a different user. But same thing happens. No temperature reading & no bulb working. Only getting connected and disconnected. If I run only one test agent in any raspberrypi it works properly. Why is that?

Comment: Is that a problem with  the     -Dmqtt.broker.port="1886" \ ????

Comment: Have you enrolled new device for other raspberry pi?

Comment: Yes. Now I have two devices in my management console. One is Raspi_IOT & other one is Raspi_IOT2.